# How to eliminate .0 for double number in thymeleaf 3 template?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a double variable that can have values like 45, 45.57, 234.1

Currently

```
[[${number} ]]
```

will print above numbers as
45.0
45.57
234.1

I want 45.0 to print as 45 while leaving others same as before.

How to do that in thymeleaf 3?

**#numbers.formatDecimal**

this is not found in official docs for thymeleaf. So dont know how to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation is at the following link:
[https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.9.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/expression/Numbers.html](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.9.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/expression/Numbers.html#setFormatInteger)

But there is no such method in the current version of Thymeleaf(3.0.9). You can write you own utility class and use it in your Thymeleaf pages. For example:

```
public final class NumberFormatterUtils {
    public static String formatNumber(double number) {
        NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("##.###");
        return nf.format(number);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
<span th:text="${T(packageName.NumberFormatterUtils).formatNumber(number)}" ></span>
```